# Limiting ansible playbook executing based on number of hosts in the inventory

Tags: ansible

### Requirement

I would like to limit the execution of my playbooks based on the TOTAL number of hosts existing in an inventory file.

As an example, the ansible playbook is executed when the total hosts are `<= 10` but when a new host is added into the inventory file the initial task checks for the hosts and the since the value is `>10` it should throw a fail message (or something similar).

I have the hosts limit set in a `vars.yml` file e.g.,

```yaml
allowed_hosts_count: 10
```

and the only possible solution I have at the moment is:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Check for Hosts count intially
      fail:
        msg: "Not allowed to execute playbook since devices are more than {{ allowed_hosts_count }}"
      when: "(ansible_play_hosts_all | length) > allowed_hosts_count"
      run_once: true
    - name: test
      ping:
```

#### Environment

Ansible Version

```bash
ansible [core 2.13.8]
```

### Question

Is there any other way to control execution based on hosts count in an inventory file? I am aware of the `--limit` CLI parameter which can provide execution based on hostname and patterns but nowhere does it provide any form of control based on the number of devices in an inventory file.

Are there certain caveats I need to look for when using the `ansible_play_hosts_all` variable in the playbook?

Comment: The question for you is: why would you want to fail? Are you aware that there are [strategies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html) in Ansible that helps you control how Ansible run on hosts?

Comment: "_Is there any other way to control execution based on hosts count in an inventory file?_", not I am aware of and you are using the same approach I would do. "_Are there certain caveats I need to look for when using the `ansible_play_hosts_all` variable in the playbook?_", not I am aware of.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε one reason from what I understand about strategies is, the playbook will still run. I wish to limit the execution of the playbook and the host counts is my requirement. if i understand correctly setting `serial: 5` for an inventory of 11 hosts will execute the playbook twice on 5hosts and then again for the 11th host.

Comment: You could also limit a group doing `hosts: all[:10]` if you want exactly ten hosts, but indeed, the "normal" behaviour of Ansible is to try to run, not to try to fail. As raised by @U880D, although I miss the point of wanting exactly ten hosts, maybe because your requirement is quite abstract and we are missing a use case, if I were to have that requirement I would implement it as you did, except I would put that in the `pre_tasks` rather than in the `tasks`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε so the use case here is I want to limit the execution of a particular playbook due to some constraints. I have a script that updates the values of `allowed_hosts_count` value based on certain conditions that are fulfilled and the values are `10`, `50` and `100`. You are right about putting the step in the `pre_tasks`, which I will do. It is an ansible _antipattern_ to fail a task deliberately but I do not know any other method that avoids execution when a condition is not fulfilled

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that idea; failing when a condition isn't met is not an antipattern, though it's more common to use `assert:` for this than `fail:`.

Comment: @flowerysong appreciate the feedback. Based on the discussion here, I have the potential solution as answer

Answer (score 2):

You can play around w the magic variable: `ansible_play_hosts`, and then count the hosts.
If that value is higher than your desired amount, end the play.

```yaml
- name: stop play when the total amount of hosts is higher than allowed_hosts_count
  meta: end_play
  when: ansible_play_hosts | length > allowed_hosts_count
```

Ending the play is *not* failing it.

Answer (score 1):

based on suggestions (see comments), the following solution works well:

### Code

`limit_check.yml`:

This is an Ansible Task file

```yaml
---
- name: Check for Device Limits
  ansible.builtin.assert:
    that:
    - (ansible_play_hosts_all | length) <= allowed_hosts_count
    success_msg: |-
      ALLOWED:
      Devices in Inventory: {{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}
      Valid for maximum of: {{ allowed_hosts_count }}
    fail_msg: |-
      DISALLOWED:
      Devices in Inventory: {{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}
      Valid for maximum of: {{ allowed_hosts_count }}
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

This task needs to be executed only the Controller Node, hence I have delegated it to `127.0.0.1` (assumming the playbook will be executed from the Controller Node).

`main.yml`:

this is the main playbook where the checks are conducted in `pre_tasks`

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml

  pre_tasks:
   - name: Check Limit initially
     ansible.builtin.include_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/limit_check.yml"
  tasks:
   - name: test ping
     ping:
```